# Firebase App REST API - filter query by date range

Tags: rest, firebase, api

I'm working with a Firebase REST API and performing a GET request to `api/v1/invoices?apikey=abc123` to retrieve invoices which returns the following:

```
{
    "id": "gsdfg23648967ot",
    "userId": "456uhdfgh45645",
    "number": null,
    "clientId": "hgsdfgdsfjgkrt",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-06-18T16:00:00.000Z",
    "amountGross": 28,
    "amountNet": "26",
    "amountPaid": 28,
    "paidAt": "2018-08-08T16:00:00.000Z",
    "salaryReceivedAt": null,
    "approvalDate": null,
    "approver": null,
    "rateVAT": 7.7,
    "vatTypeCode": null,
    "comments": null,
    "statusCode": 3,
    "changedAt": null,
    "createdAt": null
},
{
    "id": "tuitueryurtyu",
    "userId": "454523453245235234",
    "number": null,
    "clientId": "zzzzzzzz",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-05-07T16:00:00.000Z",
    "amountGross": 22.22,
    "amountNet": "22",
    "amountPaid": 22.22,
    "paidAt": "2018-08-20T22:00:00.000Z",
    "salaryReceivedAt": null,
    "approvalDate": null,
    "approver": null,
    "rateVAT": 7.7,
    "vatTypeCode": null,
    "comments": null,
    "statusCode": 3,
    "changedAt": null,
    "createdAt": null
},
```

I now need to be able to filter the query by date range, so it just returns all results where the `invoiceDate` is between 2 dates that I specify. I haven't been able to find any examples in the API docs on how query by date range so far or even if it is possible using the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries), you should use Range Queries, as follows:

```
https://.../invoices.json?orderBy="invoiceDate"&startAt="2018-06-18T16:00:00.000Z"&endAt="2019-06-18T16:00:00.000Z"?apikey=abc123
```

Comment: I had a feeling OP was asking about the GCP billing API https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Didn't know about this API! In both cases it seems the URI used by the OP (`api/v1/invoices?apikey=abc123`) needs to be adapted...

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out how the API works from a quick glance at the docs. I usually go to the API explorer for trying things like this, but didn't get a chance for this one yet.